# No module named bcrypt : DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10, pysftp

I am trying to install pysftp on windows as my odoo server is on windows and I used pysftp in my module.

First of all, it gives me an error `No module named pysftp`. I installed it using `pip install pysftp`
then system gives me same error for different dependencies like `paramiko,payn1,cryptography` etc. But at last, it gives me an error `No module named bcrypt` so I tried to install it using pip and it installed successfully. But when I run application it's giving me following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute

  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 246, in app
return self.app(e, s)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\http.py", line 1307, in __call__
self.load_addons()
 File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\http.py", line 1328, in load_addons
m = __import__('odoo.addons.' + module)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 81, in load_module
execfile(modfile, new_mod.__dict__)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\addons\amgl\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import models
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\addons\amgl\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import customer
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\odoo\addons\amgl\models\customer.py", line 8, in <module>
import pysftp
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\pysftp\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
import paramiko
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\paramiko\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\paramiko\transport.py", line 57, in <module>
from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\paramiko\ed25519key.py", line 17, in <module>
import bcrypt
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0e\server\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from bcrypt import _bcrypt
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

My pip version is `9.0.1` and python version is `3.5.4`

Comment: AFAIK, odoo10 is only supported by Python2.7. I think there is differences between python2 and python3 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not used proper python version with odoo10 and gets package errors. Check the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html#source-install) of odoo10 for correct python version. Use python 2.7.9 for windows to run odoo 10 as mentioned in [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html#source-install).

For installing python 2.7.9 packages, use `pip` command. For installing python3 packages, use `pip3` command.

One more thing for the pysftp package. You may get these errors because of the pysftp package is not supported on python 3.5 version. Check [pysftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp) documentation for supported python versions.

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this commond in your python/venv: `pip install bcrypt`